# <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter> configuration from java file

Tags: spring-integration

I need to configure and start the sftp inbound channel adapter from java file. Where I will declare multiple DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory configuration in java file. The attribute of DefaultSftpSessionFactory  will be taken from property file and the configuration for DefaultSftpSessionFactory  will be declared in property file. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the technique used in [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) or you need to wire up a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` with a `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` which needs a `SftpInboundFileSynchronizer`.